# How to Pass an add user function from solidity to react, In the Context.jsx file what should be the right code in React?

Tags: reactjs, function, frontend, solidity, addition

This is the solidity function where to add users and its struct:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

```
 contract Transactions{

uint32 public participant_id = 0;   // Participant ID

    struct participant {
    string userName;
    string password;
    string participantType;
    address participantAddress; // ethereum account Address
}
    mapping(uint32 => participant) public participants; // list of participants
```

// addParticipant simply add a new participant with different attributes

```
    function addParticipant(string memory _name, string memory _pass, address _pAdd, string 
     memory _pType) public returns (uint32)

{
    uint32 userId = participant_id++;//increment the participant id
    participants[userId].userName = _name;
    participants[userId].password = _pass;
    participants[userId].participantAddress = _pAdd;
    participants[userId].participantType = _pType;

    return userId;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to pass the data from the solidity struct to react in the function sendTransaction:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { contractABI, contractAddress } from "../utils/constants";
export const TransactionContext = React.createContext();

const { ethereum } = window;
const createEthereumContract = () => {
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const transactionsContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, 
signer);

return transactionsContract;// here return the transactions inside our solidity 
contract
};
export const TransactionsProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [formData, setformData] = useState({ _name: "", _pass: "", _pAdd: "", 
_pType: "" });
const handleChange = (e, name) => {
setformData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: e.target.value }));
};
const sendTransaction = async () => {
try {
  if (ethereum) {
    const { _name, _pass, _pAdd, _pType } = formData;
    const transactionsContract = createEthereumContract();
    const parsedAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther(amount);


    //Send add user with ETH
    await ethereum.request({
      method: "eth_sendTransaction",
      params: [{
        from: currentAccount,
        to: addressTo,
        gas: "0x5208", //21000 Gwei
        value: parsedAmount._hex,
      }],
    });
    //Add the transactions to blockchain  
    const transactionHash = await 
    transactionsContract.addParticipants( _name, _pass, _pAdd, _pType);

    setIsLoading(true);
    console.log(`Loading - ${transactionHash.hash}`);
    await transactionHash.wait();
    console.log(`Success - ${transactionHash.hash}`);
    setIsLoading(false);

    const transactionCount = await transactionsContract.getTransactionCount();

    setTransactionCount(transactionCount.toNumber());
    window.location.reload();
    } else {
    console.log("No ethereum object");
    }
    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    throw new Error("No ethereum object");
    }
    };

 return (
 <TransactionContext.Provider
  value={{
    transactions,
    currentAccount,
    isLoading,
    sendTransaction,
    handleChange,
    formData,}}>

  {children}
</TransactionContext.Provider>
);
};
```